# In Colossians 3:23, what is the meaning of «ἐκ ψυχῆς» and the distinction between «ποιῆτε» and «ἐργάζεσθε»?

Tags: greek, colossians

The Greek text of Col. 3:23 according to the Textus Receptus states,

> <sup>ΚΓʹ</sup> καὶ πᾶν ὃ τι ἐὰν ποιῆτε ἐκ ψυχῆς ἐργάζεσθε ὡς τῷ κυρίῳ καὶ οὐκ ἀνθρώποις <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

1. What does «ἐκ ψυχῆς» mean in this context? How should be it be translated and understood?
2. What is the distinction in meaning between the verbs «ποιῆτε» and «ἐργάζεσθε» in this context?

Comment: While I'm grateful for the bounty (!), I'm not sure the answer is really worthy! Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **(1)** What does «ἐκ ψυχῆς» mean?

It means something like "with all your might". It is attested in classical authors with this sense: see Liddell-Scott-Jones, [ψυχή, *sub* IV.4 "Phrases"](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=118923&context=lsj&action=from-search). A nice example (quoted there) is from Theocritus, [*Idyll* 8.35](https://archive.org/stream/L028GreekBucolicPoetsTheocritusBionMoschus/L028-Greek%20Bucolic%20Poets%20Theocritus%20Bion%20Moschus#page/n145/mode/1up) (trans. J.M. Edmonds) -

> βόσκοιτ’ ἐκ ψυχᾶς τὰς ἀμνάδας·
>   Feed my lambs with all your might

The same phrase is used with the same sense in [Ephesians 6:6](http://biblehub.com/ephesians/6-6.htm).

> **(2)** What is the distinction in meaning between the verbs ποιῆτε and ἐργάζεσθε?

- [ποιέω](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=86771&context=lsj&action=from-search) is the generic "make" or "do";
- [ἐργάζομαι](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=43310&context=lsj&action=from-search) has the sense of "work" or "work at" something.